# Android GRef increase when setting tag of view

Tags: android, memory, reference

I am working with a calendar activity and have implemented an adapter for handling the data. For every day in a month I have a button for which I set a tag. Then when the button is pushed I can tell which date it is from the tag. It is possible to skip to next/last month and thereby changing the data for the calendar view. However my problem is that every time i set the tag of the button(as the views are reused) the GRef is increased and never released and when it hits 2000 the app chrashes. When uncommenting the line of code setting the tag the Gref is not increased and the app does not chrash.
The following method is from my adapter:

```
 private int key = Resource.Id.string_key;     
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                View row = convertView;
                if (row == null)
                {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)_context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
                    row = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.calendar_grid_cell, parent, false);
                }

                // Get a reference to the Day gridcell
                gridcell = (Button)row.FindViewById(Resource.Id.calendar_day_gridcell);
                gridcell.SetOnClickListener(this);
                string[] words = list[position].Split(delimiterChars);
                gridcell.Text = words[2];
                gridcell.SetTag(key, words[1]);

                return row;
            }
```

Do anyone have a suggestion for what I can do? I have tried setting the tag property to null before setting the new tag- Or Should I just avoid using tags and find some other way?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is twofold:

1. You're calling [View.SetTag(int, Java.Lang.Object)](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aAndroid.Views.View.SetTag).
2. There is an implicit conversion from [string to Java.Lang.Object](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=ecma%3a3337%23Object%2fO%2fConversion%2f44).

So this:

```
gridcell.SetTag(key, words[1])
```

is morally the equivalent of:

```
Java.Lang.Object tmp = words[1];
gridcell.SetTag(key, tmp);
```

This causes a gref to be consumed, and it likely won't ever be collected, because Android is holding onto the Dalvik-side `java.lang.String` instance, which means Mono for Android's GC will believe that the `tmp` instance cannot be collected.

Fortunately, *we* know better, and can behave accordingly. Change your code to:

```
using (var tag = new Java.Lang.String(words[1]))
    gridcell.SetTag(key, tag);
```

This will `Dispose()` of the wrapper instance, which is fine (*in this case!*) because we don't need it, and we *know* we don't need it.

**Note**: You must be [very careful](http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Architecture#Premature_Dispose%28%29_Calls) when [making use of things you "know"](http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Garbage_Collection#Helping_the_GC).

So that's the init side of things. The lookup side of things is the same-but-different:

```
using (var tag = new Java.Lang.String("some-tag")) {
    var gridcell = row.FindViewWithTag(tag).JavaCast<Button>();
    // use gridcell...
}
```

This works because [View.findViewWithTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag%28java.lang.Object%29) is documented as using `Object.equals()` and not reference equality, and since we're using strings here we're using `String.equals()`, which performs value equality.

If grefs are a major concern, you could go one step further and dispose of the `gridcell` gref, *unless* `gridcell` could be a C# subclass. (*Knowing* this requires access to your `.axml`.)

```
private int key = Resource.Id.string_key;     
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)_context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        row = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.calendar_grid_cell, parent, false);
    }

    // Get a reference to the Day gridcell
    using (var gridcell = row.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.calendar_day_gridcell)) {
        gridcell.SetOnClickListener(this);
        string[] words = list[position].Split(delimiterChars);
        gridcell.Text = words[2];
        using (var tag = new Java.Lang.String(words[1]))
            gridcell.SetTag(key, tag);
    }

    return row;
}
```