# MvvmCross Xamarin Droid crash due to GREF > 2000

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

On an recent 'remote control' app that we're developing, we are since a few days running in unexpected crashes due to the # GREFs going above 2000 in the simulator. On real hardware, it takes a lot longer but eventually happens as well (I understood the simulator limit of 2000 is  not present on real HW). I've researched most of the SO topics with the same subject, but no real similarities to our situation. UI isn't that complex, basically uses a few separate screens for setup, after which it works in a TabView with a number of pages. Nothing fancy.

On the last crash, I captured the debug logs with the summary of the GREFs.

```
    03-25 20:29:22.184 D/dalvikvm( 1686): GREF has increased to 2001
    03-25 20:29:22.184 W/dalvikvm( 1686): JNI global reference table (0xbb68f218) dump:
    03-25 20:29:22.184 W/dalvikvm( 1686):   Last 10 entries (of 2001):
    03-25 20:29:22.184 W/dalvikvm( 1686):      2000: 0xb54e0f20 java.lang.Class<mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor>
    03-25 20:29:22.184 W/dalvikvm( 1686):      1999: 0xb5652570 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    03-25 20:29:22.184 W/dalvikvm( 1686):      1998: 0xb5652af8 mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor
    03-25 20:29:22.184 W/dalvikvm( 1686):      1997: 0xb5652ce0 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    03-25 20:29:22.184 W/dalvikvm( 1686):      1996: 0xb56539e8 mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):      1995: 0xb5653460 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):      1994: 0xb56537e8 mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):      1993: 0xb5653bb8 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):      1992: 0xb5654358 mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):      1991: 0xb5654338 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):   Summary:
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):       318 of java.lang.Class (166 unique instances)
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):        20 of android.w03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):        18 of java.lang.String (18 unique instances)
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):       440 of java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError (440 unique instances)
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):         1 of java.lang.Boolean
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):        13 of java.lang.Integer (13 unique instances)
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):         1 of java.io.File
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):        49 of java.lang.ref.WeakReference (49 unique instances)
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/da03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):         1 of dalvik.system.PathClassLoader
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):         7 of android.graphics.Bitmap (7 unique instances)
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):         1 of android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):         2 of android.os.Handler (2 unique instances)
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):         1 of android.content.ContentProvider$Transport
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):        20 of android.content.Intent (20 unique instances)
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):        29 of android.widget.EditText (29 unique instances)
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):        15 of android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser (15 unique instances)
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):         1 of android.database.ContentObserver$Transport
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):       225 of android.widget.TextView (225 unique instances)
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):        13 of android.os.Bundle (13 unique instances)
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):         1 of android.os.Looper
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):         2 of org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl (1 unique instances)
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):        29 of android.text.SpannableStringBuilder (29 unique instances)
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):         5 of android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputMethodCallback (5 unique instances)
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):         1 of android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager$1
    The program 'Mono' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):        15 of android.view.ViewRootImpl$W (15 unique instances)
    03-25 20:29:22.194 W/dalvikvm( 1686):         8 of android.widget.CheckBox (8 unique instances)
```

What strikes me is the high number of 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError' instances (440). I suspect the log is not complete as the other apparent high runner 'mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor' is not in the list. Second observation is the sequence of those two alternating instances running the GREFs over the top and crashing the app.

Question: any idea what can cause the abundance of these 2 GREF instances ? What do they mean and what creates them (which may lead me to finding the root cause of the crashes).

Thx !

Comment: The only real problem I've ever seen in Mvx with GREF was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842864/why-does-the-gref-go-too-high-when-i-put-a-mvxbindablespinner-in-a-mvxbindableli. It might be worth trying to work out which part of your app is leaking the GREFs and getting that as a simpler reproducible sample - then it'll be easier to work out what the leak is and to plug it. It might also be worth tagging questions like this with `Xamarin` and/or `MonoDroid` - as that gets the attention of the Xamarin runtime ninjas who can assist with debugging and logging tips.

Comment: Thx. I noticed this SO post but couldn't immediately make the link. I am using TimePickers within a TabView and it seems like the problems started after activating/binding those to the associated viewmodel. COuld that cause similar issues ? I'll do an experiment with removing the bindings/viewmodel to see if the issue goes away

Comment: I don't see much in MvxDatePicker or MvxTimePicker - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxDatePicker.cs - but I can believe anything. At the moment, sadly you're the one who can see the leak and can do the experiments - sorry - but the experimentation way is a very good way to find out where the leak is.

Comment: All the links I can see for `noclassdeffounderror` suggest Android library import issues - is there some other jar library or component you've included?

Comment: no, only Mvx plugins...additional observation : when running app in emulator with debugger connected (visual studio), this happens rather quickly. When starting app in emulator disconnected, it doesn't (at least for the several hours I tested.